# Cannot sign in to Google Play Games with my app

Tags: java, android, google-signin, google-play-games

I have recently published an app in the Google Play Store, I used LibGDX to develope the app. Now I wanted to add high scores with the Google Play Games app. I followed the steps in https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling . However, I cannot sign in to the Google Play Games in my app.

Here is the code I am using to connect to the Google Play Games Services:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

        config.useAccelerometer = false;
        config.useCompass = false;

        initialize(new LibGDXBridge(), config);

        GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
          new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build());

        startActivityForResult(googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), 9001);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task =
          GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent);

        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            // Do something.
        } catch (ApiException apiException) {
                System.out.println(apiException);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the code until "GoogleSignInClient" is code for LibGDX.

Whenever I run the app I always enter the catch block, the output is:

*I/System.out: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4:*

On the page https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#SIGN_IN_REQUIRED I have found out that this stands for SIGN_IN_REQUIRED.
I also have to mention that when I run the app, there is at the beginning a Google Play Games pop up, but then it just vanishes, I cannot enter my account or do anything else.
I tried this with a debug version of the app, I just connected my phone to my PC and installed the app via Android Studio, could this be a problem?

Thanks for your efforts in advance.

**EDIT:** I have now solved the problem. It was indeed the debug version of the app, I have created a new ClientId and used the SHA1 fingerprint of the debug keystore and now it works.